# Passing parameters to view blocks in Twig

Tags: views

Running Drupal 8.9.18

I have a string that I want to pass to a Drupal block for use in a contextual filter. In a twig template I have a view that creates a simple list of the terms to use. I extract the string from the result array, map the required string to a variable that I pass as a parameter to another view block:

```
{% set view-output = drupal_block('views_block:view1-block_1') %}

{% for item in view-output.content['#view'].result %}

  {% set qParam = item.taxonomy_term_field_data_name | render | striptags %}
  {% if drupal_block('views_block:view2-block_1', qParam )is not empty %}
    {{ drupal_block('views_block:view-name-block_1', qParam) }}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

The expression `item.taxonomy_term_field_data_name | render | striptags` gives me the values I expect from the view output.

I get the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> Drupal\twig_tweak\TwigExtension::drupalBlock() must be of the type
> array, string given,

Question:  how can I pass `qParam` as an array (it's a single value). I've tried using
`{% set qParam = qParam|merge(..) %}` inside the for loop but the (..) bit is a mystery to me.

Or is there a better way of nesting queries that I don't know?

Note that I am not conversant with coding in PHP and want to stick with using Twig alone.

Thanks in anticipation for any help

Answer (score 2):

following the error-message you probably just use an array with a single value as second argument, e.g

```
{{ drupal_block('xx', {qParam: qParam} ) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I'll try that. I've actually found a workaround using a contextual filter to identify a specific path component rather than using a query parameter. This does what I want but I'd be interested to solve the original problem